# Trying to identify a short story of missed opportunities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

From what I recall, it had artwork and the story went as follows:

- Boy aspires to be astronaut but when he's old enough he doesn't qualify
- When he's older they start accepting ***everyone*** (except the elderly) and he's disqualified again.

Throughout his life his dreams keep evading him.

This short story was set in the future. I do recall there being robots as well. I think initially he wasn't qualified then they accepting everyone for manual labor/colonizing but he was to old to make the trip. I don't recall the main characters name unfortunately. I have a feeling it's an Asimov or Bradbury tale but I could be wrong.

Comment: This seems quite sparse. Can you remember any additional details? Was it set in the future, for example. Why did they start accepting ***everyone***? What was the main character's name? Why did he flunk out when he was younger?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like real life to this guy. But maybe I'm just bitter.

Answer (score 4):

["Requiem" by Robert A. Heinlein (1940)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_%28short_story%29), maybe? Reads as a sequel to his book, The Man Who Sold the Moon, but was actually published before it.

> The story centers around Delos David Harriman, the lead character of
>   "The Man Who Sold the Moon". **Harriman, a tycoon and latter-day robber
>   baron, had always dreamed of going to the Moon, and had spent much of
>   his career and resources making space flight a practical commercial
>   enterprise. Unfortunately, his business partners prevented him from
>   taking the early flights because they could not risk the public face
>   of their company. Now an old man, Harriman has still not been to the
>   Moon, a fact that frustrates him, since he lives in a world where
>   space travel is so commonplace that carnivals have their own
>   barnstorming spacecraft. Although no longer bound by his contractual
>   obligations, he is now too old to pass the medical examination needed
>   for space travel.**
>
> Very wealthy, Harriman bribes two spacemen to help him get to the Moon
>   after encountering them at a funfair in Butler, a small town outside
>   Kansas City, Missouri (Heinlein's birthplace), where they sell rides
>   on their old, somewhat run-down ship.
>
> The three of them fight many obstacles, including Harriman's heirs,
>   who want him declared mentally incompetent or senile before he can
>   spend their inheritance. In the end, Harriman finally makes it to the
>   Moon, only to die on the surface soon after landing, content at
>   finally having reached his goal. His body is left there, with his
>   epitaph scrawled on the tag from an oxygen bottle. It is Robert Louis
>   Stevenson's "Requiem", which is inscribed on his own headstone in
>   Samoa.
>
> ```
> Under the wide and starry sky
> Dig the grave and let me lie:
> Glad did I live and gladly die,
> And I laid me down with a will!
>
> This be the verse you grave for me:
> Here he lies where he longed to be;
> Home is the sailor, home from sea,
> And the hunter home from the hill.
> ```

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic story. I don't remember the lead character being a business tycoon or reaching his goal but that could have been lost to memory. I'll pick it up and let everyone know if that's it. Thanks!